# is this allowed in C++ pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

i am learning c++ and i find this bit confusing about the pointers . is it allowed or is it possible to modify the variable int a using pointer variable ?

here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int a ; // int variable 
    int *p ; // pointer 


    a = 10 ;
    *p =15 ; 

    std:: cout << a ;
    return 0; 
};
```

does *p = 15 change the value of a ?
i got error when i tried to run the code :

```
zsh: bus error
```

Comment: Currently your problem is you did not set the pointer to point to any valid location. ***does *p = 15 change the value of a ?*** No `p` is not pointing to `a`

Comment: As you have it, no.   `p` is an uninitialised pointer, so evaluating `*p` (or, even worse, assigning a value to it, as you have) gives undefined behaviour.     The way to get `p` to point at `a` is to either initialise `p` as `int *p = &a` or assign it (e.g. `p = &a`).  After doing either initialisation or assignment of `p` to contain `&a`, the assignment `*p = 15` will have the effect of changing `a`  (as long as `p` itself is not reassigned to point at something else).

Comment: Note that in C++ pointers (while useful, and still shown in many textbools as one of the first things to learn) are not the thing you will probably use most.

Answer (score 5):

There's no relationship between `p` and `a`. `p` points to invalid memory, and dereferencing or assigning to it is undefined behavior.

If you *want* modifications to `p` to affect `a`, you need to set where it points to.

```
int a;
int *p = &a;
```

Comment: While it's clear what you meant from your example code, this: "dereferencing or assigning to it" would probably be better said: "and reading or assigning to the dereferenced pointer"

Answer (score 1):

Silvio's answer is correct.
Bus errors occur when your processor cannot even attempt the memory access requested.
This usually happens when using a processor instruction with an address that does not satisfy its alignment requirements.

you can read more about this [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the address of variable `a` to the pointer `p`.

```
p = &a;
```

Now, if you will change the value of the pointer to `15` it will be reflected in the variable `a`. And you won't get an error.